# How to preserve style of parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of code in a foreach:

```
FOREACH:
<div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 50% !important" id="pageList_{{ presentationPage.position }}">
    <a href="/customer/presentations/{{ id }}/edit?position={{ presentationPage.position }}">
        <div class="slide-preview" style="background-color:{% if (presentationPage.position == activePresentationPage.position) %}#ffffff{% else %}#bbbbbb{% endif %}; border: 1px solid #000000; width:100%; padding:2px 5px; margin:5px; color:#000000; text-align:center;">
                                            {{ presentationPage.position }}
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
ENDFOREACH
```

Which looks like this when rendered:

[image: Before]

However, when I add something similar as an element or a div as you can see in the code below:

```
<div>
    FOREACH:
    <div class="col-md-1" style="max-width: 50% !important" id="pageList_{{ presentationPage.position }}">
        <a href="/customer/presentations/{{ id }}/edit?position={{ presentationPage.position }}">
            <div class="slide-preview" style="background-color:{% if (presentationPage.position == activePresentationPage.position) %}#ffffff{% else %}#bbbbbb{% endif %}; border: 1px solid #000000; width:100%; padding:2px 5px; margin:5px; color:#000000; text-align:center;">
                                            {{ presentationPage.position }}
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    ENDFOREACH
</div>
```

The entire thing looks like this when rendered:

[image: After]

And I can't seem to find out why. A simple inspect doesn't bring any insights.

Comment: Try add a style to your parent div with properties of `width : 100%; height : 100%;`

Comment: Could you provide the html that is and isn't working in snippets ( Ctr-M )?

Comment: If you're using bootstrap try adding `class="row"` on the wrapper div.

Comment: Thank you rgin, that was it. Setting width/height did not work aswell. Adding class="row" did! If you provide it as an answer I will be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0):

That is because the div that you put around the two elements doesn't have a specified width and height. Therefore the div will base its width and height on the size of its content. Then, your two elements will base their width and height on their parent's width and height, so it will get very small.

So if you give the parent div a width and height it should work out okay.